# key.pressEvent(), no ejecuta la tarea indicada

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

quisiera saber como puedo ejecutar una funcion al presionar la tecla enter, en un widget en especifico.

Para este caso, estoy tratando de ejecutar una función al momento de presionar enter en el qlineedit. pero no responde esta es la imagen de la interfaz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication, QAction
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent


class Primera(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui",self)

    def keyPressEvent(self,obj,event):
        if obj is self.l_codigo:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                self.setFocus(self.edit)
            event.accept()


app = QApplication([])
p = Primera()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: podrias publicar tu archivo .ui

Comment: ¿que es edit????

Comment: Edit es una label.con el valor de 34

Comment: ¿Para que quieres colocarle el focus al QLabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QLineEdit` tiene la señal `returnPressed` que se emite cuando presionas enter.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic


class Primera(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui",self)
        self.l_codigo.returnPressed.connect(self.edit.setFocus)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Primera()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Por otro lado al usar keyPressEvent estas sobreescribiendo el evento de `Primera`, eso no tiene nada que ver con el QLineEdit, si deseas usar eventFilter(solo usa este método si no existe la señal adecuada) debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic


class Primera(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui",self)
        self.l_codigo.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if obj is self.l_codigo and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
                self.edit.setFocus()
        return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self,obj,event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Primera()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Como te das cuenta el segundo método es menos elegante, más extenso.

---

Si sobreescribimos keyPressEvent() correctamente deberia ser de la siguiente forma:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic


class Primera(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui",self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            print("event")
        return QMainWindow.keyPressEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Primera()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Pero el problema es que se lanzara para todos los widgets que sean hijos de `Principal`

Comment: dentro del eventFilter puedo añadir otro evento utilizando elif¿?

Comment: @Revsky01 sí, pero esa forma de hacerlo es poco elegante

Comment: @Revsky01 mi primera solucion ocupa una línea, con eventFilter son más líneas :(

Comment: ok gracias lo hare como me lo indicas gracias por la ayuda 

Comment: @Revsky01 la solucion que implemente usando el eventFilter con el QMenuBar es un hack, no habia señal asi que busca la forma de más bajo nivel. las señales en cambio son más fáciles de usar.

Comment: Comentáis que ```QLineEdit``` tiene la señal ```returnPressed``` que se emite cuando presionas ```enter```. ¿qué señal sería la equivalente para un ```QPushButton```?